# How to use oracle libraries in C++

Tags: c++, oracle

If I want to use Oracle libraries in C++ project, what do I have to do?
Here is what I did so far:

- Downloaded version 11 (newest Version 11.2.0.4.0) package from here(first and fifth packages): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html
- Also this patch: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/occidownloads-083553.html

Then in the Linker->Additional library directories specified

```
D:\instantclient_11_2\vc10
```

Path where the patch was downloaded.

And in C/C++->Additional include directories, specified this path:

`D:\instantclient_11_2\sdk\include`

My question is am I missing something? Do I need to take some additional steps to be able to use oracle libraries in C++ project? Like install something else, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are needing clarification on setting up 3rd party dependencies. Inferring that Visual Studio is the IDE you are using:

From what you've mentioned, the only thing that hasn't been addressed is adding the names of the `.lib` files to the linker->input->additional dependencies field. Also ensure that your include and linker directories *are* pointing to folders with `.h` and `.lib` files respectively.

Finally the `.dll` files need to be in a place your exe/library can access them, the easiest way to acheive this is to copy+paste the `.dlls` to your output directory.

Comment: @userq it may be helpful if you post an error message you are getting when you try to use? Can only infer what steps you haven't / have performed in your setup.

Comment: If @ForemanBob was able to deduce what you missed based on the information already given. You should always help the people who are trying to help you. If your runtime client is not Version 11.2.0.4.0, you've downloaded the wrong version of the Instant Client. The version numbers must match **exactly**

Answer (score 0):

On Linux set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the `instantclient_11_2`,

On Windows, set `PATH` to locate the `instantclient_11_2` directory.

Comment: Have you tried to compile some basic program using oracle libraries?